# window.URL.createObjectURL with file path parameter

Tags: javascript

window.URL.createObjectURL can be used with a file parameter, but I need use it with a string path to file (ie: File:///c:/music. Mp3)
Anyone have idea how do it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not allowed due to security restrictions. If that were possible, anyone could write a webpage that could download all of the files on your computer. That is why you have to use a `File` object, because you can only get those from user input.

If you elaborate on what you are trying to solve, I can try to give other suggestions.